# bash array list only /dev/sd[a-z][a-z] pattern

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, unix, pattern-matching

I use the Subshell with the Array, to list all HDD Devices.

```
hdd=($(lsblk --nodeps -n -o name))
```

I want only the `/dev/sd*` Devices.

So how can I use a Regex, to list only the `/dev/sd*` Unix HDD Devices?

Comment: `lsblk --nodeps -n -o name | grep ^sd` ?

Comment: works as expected, thanks :)

Comment: Use: `lsblk --nodeps -n -o name /dev/sd*`

Comment: Because SCSI disks have major device number 8:  `lsblk --nodeps -n -o name -I8`

Comment: @John1024 : Nice note, ^

Comment: @John1024 Why not making it an answer? Looks like that is what the OP *really* wants.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu and don't have the `I` switch: `lsblk: invalid option -- 'I'`

Comment: Use `-S` in that case.

Comment: @JamesBrown As I read the release notes, the `-I` option requires [util-linux version 2.22](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/v2.22-ReleaseNotes) or better.  Version 2.22 was released in 2012.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks.  I added it as an answer.

Comment: @John1024 I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 at work, guess they were slow in their turns. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 2):

Because SCSI disks have major device number 8:

```
lsblk --nodeps -n -o name -I8
```

`-I` is short for `--include` and tells lsblk which major device numbers to include in the output.  `8` is for [SCSI disk devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devices.txt) which corresponds to `/dev/sd*`.

This was tested on `lsblk` from `util-linux 2.28`.  The `--include` option appears to require [util-linux 2.22](http://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/v2.22-ReleaseNotes) or better. 2.22 was released in 2012.

#### Documentation

From `man lsblk`:

> **-I, --include list**
>  Include devices specified by the comma-separated list of major device numbers.  The filter is applied
>   to the top-level devices only.

#### Variation

A similar but more inclusive option is `-S`:

```
lsblk --nodeps -n -o name -S
```

`-S` lists all SCSI devices.  This will, for example, show SCSI DVD drives (major device number 11) along with SCSI hard disks.  `-S` requires [util-linux version 2.23](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/v2.23-ReleaseNotes) or better